# How to test a method using sleep() with Java?

Tags: java, junit

I have the following method and I am struggling to get 100% code coverage.

```
public final class SleepingHelper {
    public static void sleepInMillis(Duration timeOfNextTry) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(timeOfNextTry.toMillis());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The question is how can I force `Thread.sleep` to throw an exception?

Edit: since it was marked as duplicate, I am still wondering what I would assert in the test ? The other question Is more generic.

Comment: the focus on a 100% coverage is delusory. Testing this method does not give you any further addition besides an increased coverage. What is the purpose of testing this method ? None besides that Thread.sleep is working. It is obvious due to your question about the assertion that it is a test you dont want to write !

Comment: I agree, but I am working on a project where we enforce 100% code coverage.

Comment: if this is a project obligation I would create a test without any assertion - you get your 100% and the test will not fail... or `AssertEquals(true, true)`.

Comment: Make sens. I will do something like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to interrupt it from another thread. For example:

```
 Thread t = new Thread() {
     public void run () {
        SleeperMillis.sleepInMillis(new Duration(10000000l));
     }
 }.start();
 Thread.sleep(100); // let the other thread start
 t.interrupt;
```

Comment: Thx! this helps, but what would you assert in a test?

Comment: I don't know, it depends on what kind of behavior or contract you are trying to verify. What it is you want to test specifically? That jdk implements sleep() correctly? It is usually not a good idea to test the behavior of functions that you did not write

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to actually interrupt the thread. You can use PowerMockito to mock the static method `Thread.sleep()`

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Thread.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void testSleepInMillis() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Thread.class);
        PowerMockito.doThrow(new InterruptedException ()).when(Thread.class);

        try {
            SleepHelper.sleepInMillis(11);
            fail("expected exception");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("all good");
        }

    }
```

Comment: FTR this doesn't work in the new Mockito static mocking...

org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: It is not possible to mock static methods of java.lang.Thread to avoid interfering with class loading what leads to infinite loops

Answer (score 4):

You don't test it, because you can't assert its results, and you can't assert it because `Thread.sleep` is not accurate or guaranteed to sleep for this duration of time, and the test results will differ from run to run.

`Mocking` is a better option here.

Btw, it is not just that your tests aren't predictable, your code that uses `Thread.sleep` in production is going to be unpredictable for the same reasons. `Thread.sleep(some magic number goes here)` usually indicates a badly written program.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother testing it. 100% coverage is excessive. However, you could do it like this:

```
@Test
public void testException() throws Exception {

    // Capture the system error stream, so that we can test that the expected exception is printed.
    ByteArrayOutputStream capturedErrors = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(capturedErrors));

    // Create a new thread on which to run the candidate method.
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SleepingHelper.sleepInMillis(Duration.ofMillis(10));
        }
    };

    // Start the second thread.
    thread.start();

    // Interrupt the second thread. (The candidate method hasn't finished yet. It takes 10 milliseconds to run.)
    thread.interrupt();

    // Wait for the thread to die (and write out the stack-trace).
    thread.join();

    // Test that the expected exception's stack trace was printed to the system error stream.
    // The output should start with the exception's name.
    String output = capturedErrors.toString();
    int lengthOfExceptionName = "java.lang.InterruptedException".length();
    assertEquals(output.substring(0, lengthOfExceptionName), "java.lang.InterruptedException");
}
```